# What should i do to optimize this C++ code? I don't have any idea which statement is taking more execution time

Tags: c++

I was to solve one question on hackerrank related to lower bound in C++. My code was able to pass all the test cases which had no time limit but failed in all time bound test cases. You can find the hackerrank question from this link:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cpp-lower-bound/problem?utm_campaign=social-buttons&utm_medium=linkedin&utm_source=challenge

Below is my code. Please tell me how I can optimize it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int elementCount = 0, queryCount = 0, tempElement = 0;
    std::cin >> elementCount;

    for(int i=0; i<elementCount; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> tempElement;
        v.push_back(tempElement);
    }

    std::vector<int>::iterator elementPosition;
    const std::vector<int>::iterator midElement = v.begin() + v.size()/2;
    std::cin >> queryCount;

    for(int q=0; q<queryCount; ++q)
    {
        std::cin >> tempElement;
        if(tempElement <= *midElement)
        {
            elementPosition = find(v.begin(), midElement+1, tempElement);
            if(elementPosition == (midElement+1))
            {
                elementPosition = lower_bound(v.begin(), midElement, tempElement);
                std::cout << "No " << (elementPosition-v.begin())+1 << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Yes " << (elementPosition-v.begin())+1 << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            elementPosition = find(midElement+1, v.end(), tempElement);
            if(elementPosition != v.end())
            {
                std::cout << "Yes " << (elementPosition-v.begin())+1 << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                elementPosition = lower_bound(midElement+1, v.end(), tempElement);
                std::cout << "No " << (elementPosition-v.begin())+1 << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: start with vector::reserve

Comment: `find(v.begin(), midElement+1, tempElement)` This does a linear search through the vector. They probably expect you to do a binary search (`lower_bound`).

Comment: Use a profiler.

Comment: It sounds like it's time to run a profiler. Figuring out which statements take the longest is their main purpose.

Comment: @Justin i thought of using binary_search but to solve the problem i need to print index of the element if found but binary_search only return bool value that's why i am using find to accomplish both the tasks.

Comment: @n.pronouns'm. I don't know about profiler. I will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: @Chris I don't know about profiler. I will look into it. Thank you

Comment: What do you hope to learn from these contest/challenge/competitive coding/hacking sites? If it's to learn C++, you won't learn anything there. Like in this case, the correct solution is based on a mathematical or a programming trick. If you don't know what the trick is and attempt to code a brute-force approach, the program either runs slow, or fails to handle an obscure edge case. If you're trying to learn C++, you won't learn anything from meaningless online contest sites [but only from a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik i am using this platform to practice whatever i have learnt about C++.

Comment: Every C++ textbook has plenty of practice examples that are designed to improve your understanding of the material that's been presented in each chapter. You will find those examples far more useful and informative than this. Does this "hackerrank" web site teach you how to properly implement a binary search? Of course not. You will only find an explanation, and some examples, in a textbook.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik You're right. So can you suggest me any good book so that i can gain more knowledge about best practices.

Comment: See stackoverflow's [canonical list of C++ textbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Thank you. I will checkout the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have over complicated the solution with unnecessary `find()` + `lower_bound`.

- Just use [`lower_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) to find the element
- If found, print yes
- If not, print no

```
    auto elementPosition = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), tempElement);
    size_t pos = std::distance(v.begin(), elementPosition);
    if (v[pos] == tempElement) {
        //print yes
    } else {
       // print no
    }
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Now i realized the mistake that i made! Find was useless there.